# How to resolve UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules

I am learning Nodejs and I am trying to implement the **Promise** concept.
When I run my application I am getting below exception:

```
Example app listening on port 3000!
TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined
    at D:\nodesjapp\rsrest-api\helpers\query.js:10:8
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (D:\nodesjapp\rsrest-api\helpers\query.js:1:45)
    at D:\nodesjapp\rsrest-api\app-middlewares\auth.js:30:22
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:5576) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

My query helper is **query.js:**

```
   module.exports = async (conn, q, params) => new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) => {
      const handler = (error, result) => {
          if (error) {
          reject(error);
          return;
        }
        resolve(result);
      }
      conn.query(q, params, handler);
    }).catch(console.log);
```

I am calling this login API which is written in **auth.js:**

```
 const express = require('express');
    const connection = require('../helpers/connection');
    const query = require('../helpers/query');    
    const router = express.Router();
    const dbConfig = require('../dbConfig');    
    const create = require('../crud/create');
    
    router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
      const { username, password } = req.body;
      const conn = await connection(dbConfig).catch(e => {});
      const user = await query(
        conn,
        `SELECT id, username FROM USERS WHERE username=? AND password=MD5(?)`,
        [username, password]
      );
      res.send(user[0] || { id: null, username: null });
    });    
    module.exports = router;
```

My database configuration are written in **dbConfig.js:**

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv") 
dotenv.config();
// Get the Host from Environment or use default
const host = process.env.DB_HOST || 'localhost';
// Get the User for DB from Environment or use default
const user = process.env.DB_USER || 'root';
// Get the Password for DB from Environment or use default
const password = process.env.DB_PASS || 'root';
// Get the Database from Environment or use default
const database = process.env.DB_DATABASE || 'twitter_clone';
module.exports = { host, user, password, database };
```

Comment: The `conn` variable is undefined, which been passed from outer function, the outer module code will be needed for people to help fix this.

Comment: @ObooCheng just now I added more details, let me know if anything else is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error itself is that your conn variable has no value, reasons can be multiple. Have a look at this line

```js
      const conn = await connection(dbConfig).catch(e => {});
```

first, you have the catch block and you are not handling the error, so if the error occurred you won't get anything as a response, be sure every error be treated properly.

and make sure `connection` is returning the connection object as expected, instead of return undefined or other condition.

Comment: As per your suggestion, I modified my code to handle the exception and now it's working. Thank you!